# Odd behavior of window.location.href in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a url stored as a value in a radio input element. When a user selects one of the elements it runs a function to send them to the given url. The code reads the elements value attribute and then runs encodeURI on it before assigning it to window.location.href

Javascript

```
function go(e){
  window.location.href=encodeURI(e.value);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" onclick="go(this)" name="first" value="https://site.othersite.com/login.aspx?client=cname&LT=P" >
```

This Works correctly in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. What happens in IE is strange. First the browser first interprets the &LT in the attribute as a less than symbol. This by it's self is not too weird since that is the escape string for a less than symbol. What's odd is that if this is escaped as

```
https://site.othersite.com/login.aspx?client=cname&amp;LT=P
```

Then it appears correctly when printed out or alerted on the page. However when it is passed to window.location.href it again interprets the &LT as a less than symbol.

If you escape the string in the attribute as

```
https://site.othersite.com/login.aspx?client=cname&amp;amp;LT=P
```

Then it appears to work correctly in IE however this produces incorrect results in other browsers.

All IE testing was done on IE 9

Any idea what the correct way of dealing with this is?

Comment: what happens if you just assign the url to .href without the encodeURI?

Comment: `encodeURI(e.value);` is wrong...

Comment: TO be fair the encodeURI was added after trying to find something to fix the problem. I observed the same behavior regardless of it's presence.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your value to just the parameters you're passing

```
<input type="radio" onclick="go(this)" name="first" value="client=cname&amp;LT=P" >
```

then append it as an encodedURIcomponent() to your URL

```
window.location.href="https://site.othersite.com/login.aspx?" + encodeURIComponent(e.value);
```

output:

```
https://site.othersite.com/login.aspx?client%3Dcname%26LT%3DP
```

Comment: This won't work since the domain is likely to change between links.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using encodeURI

Your code should just be:

```
function go(elem){
    window.location.href = elem.value; 
}
```

if you were just adding a value to a querystring, than you would need to use it.

```
function go(elem){
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/foo/?redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(elem.value); 
}
```

Comment: That's fair and it is in fact the way I had it before I started looking for help. Removing it produced the same outcome.